# How to reuse dynamic ID in react in different components

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a modal in one of my folders in react. What it does is basically it grabs the ID that has been passed whenever a user sends a document to firestore. What I want to achieve is when editing the document, it comes with an ID from firestore, I want to use that particular ID in another component.

Here's the code to explain better:

```
const EditReportMcs = ({ id, antibiotics, sensitivity }) => {
  const [createAntibiotics, setCreateAntibiotics] = useState(antibiotics)
  const [createSensitivity, setCreateSensitivity] = useState(sensitivity)

  const { userId } = useParams();
  
  const updateTask = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
      const taskDocument = doc(db, "vet/" + userId , "reportabs", id);
      await updateDoc(taskDocument, {
        antibiotics: createAntibiotics,
        sensitivity: createSensitivity,
      });
      window.location.reload();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
        data-bs-toggle="modal"
        data-bs-target={`#id${id}`}
      >
        <EditNoteRoundedIcon/>
      </button>

      <div
        className="modal fade"
        id={`id${id}`}
        tabIndex="-1"
        aria-labelledby="editLabel"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5 className="modal-title" id="editLabel" style={{color:"green"}}>
                Update Mcs
              </h5>
              <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              <form>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="pair-1">
                      Antibiotics and Sensitivity
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Enter antibiotics"
                    defaultValue={createAntibiotics}
                    onChange={(e) => setCreateAntibiotics(e.target.value)}
                  /> 
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Enter sensitivity"
                    defaultValue={createSensitivity}
                    onChange={(e) => setCreateSensitivity(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                  Close
                </button>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                  onClick={e => updateTask(e)}
                >
                  Update History
                </button>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

The code snippet above is editing data from a firestore subcollection. Assuming the ID is ("Int29WJx6l2GGrzJrqwA") that is, from the code above if const id = `id${id}`, I want to reuse this particular ID in another component

What I tried was to use a `createContext` in order to pull that ID plus I also tried exporting the ID as a variable but it still didn't work.

Here's the code:

```
export const VetContext = createContext()

return (
  <>
  const reportId = `id${id}`
    <VetContext.Provider value={reportId}>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
        data-bs-toggle="modal"
        data-bs-target={`#id${id}`}
      >
        <EditNoteRoundedIcon/>
      </button>

      <div
        className="modal fade"
        id={`id${id}`}
        tabIndex="-1"
        aria-labelledby="editLabel"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5 className="modal-title" id="editLabel" style={{color:"green"}}>
                Update Mcs
              </h5>
              <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              <form>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="pair-1">
                      Antibiotics and Sensitivity
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Enter antibiotics"
                    defaultValue={createAntibiotics}
                    onChange={(e) => setCreateAntibiotics(e.target.value)}
                  /> 
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Enter sensitivity"
                    defaultValue={createSensitivity}
                    onChange={(e) => setCreateSensitivity(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                  Close
                </button>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                  onClick={e => updateTask(e)}
                >
                  Update History
                </button>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </VetContext.Provider>
  </>
 )
```

From the EditReportMcs I can see my reportId in the clg[image]

Then in the other component I tried accessing the value ID using a `useContext` hook below:-

```js
const data = useContext(VetContext);
console.log("getTheParticularID", data)
```

Currently all those didn't work. How exactly would I go about using that ID in different components?

Where I want to render the id:-

```js
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./viewreportmcs.scss";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { db } from "../../firebase";
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import PreviewIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Preview';
import { VetContext } from "./EditReportMcs";



const ViewReportMcs = () => {

    // console.log("tracking mcsId", id)
    const [mcs, setMcs] = useState([]);
    const reportId = useContext(VetContext)
 
  return (
    <>
    {/* checking to see if any id is actually returned */}
     <h1> {reportId} </h1>
        </>
  )
}

export default ViewReportMcs
```

Using a Consumer in the ViewReportMcs :-

```js
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import "./viewreportmcs.scss";
    import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
    import { db } from "../../firebase";
    import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
    import PreviewIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Preview';
    import { VetContext } from "./EditReportMcs";



    const ViewReportMcs = () => {

        // console.log("tracking mcsId", id)
        const [mcs, setMcs] = useState([]);
        const reportId = useContext(VetContext)
     
      return (
        <>
        {/* checking to see if any id is actually returned */}
         <VetContext.Consumer>
    {value => {
         console.log(value);
         <h1> {reportId} </h1>
         }}
    </VetContext.Consumer>
            </>
      )
    }

    export default ViewReportMcs
```

Still I can't access the reportId in the ViewReportMcs

Comment: What/where/how is `id` passed to this `EditReportMcs` component? Where is the other component rendered that is trying to consume the provided context value? See [mcve].

Comment: @Drew Reese.. I've updated the code snippet for where the id is meant to be rendered

Comment: Where is `ViewReportMcs` rendered in relation to `EditReportMcs` and the context it provides? Consumers ***must*** be rendered within the context provider component's sub-ReactTree in order to access the context value.

Comment: @Drew Reese, I used a consumer yet I got undefined. Let me show the code

Comment: @Drew Reese, I've updated the code snippet showing where I used the consumer

Comment: I get that the context value is undefined. It's because it seems that `ViewReportMcs` isn't rendered within the `VetContext.Provider` component providing the value. All the components that need to access the context value need to be rendered under `VetContext.Provider`. Does this make sense? Where and how are both the `ViewReportMcs` and `EditReportMcs` being rendered and where does the `id` value being passed to `EditReportMcs` come from? We need to see a more complete [mcve] to provide you any more help really.

Comment: @Drew Reese the id is coming from firestore, I've shown my clg showing the id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254161/discussion-between-deezy-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share the id value from the firestore to several components you can do this using the React Context API. All components that would access the provided context value should be rendered within the component tree created by the context provider.

Example:

Create the context and provider component.

```
export const VetContext = createContext({
  reportId: null,
});

export const useVetContext = () => useContext(VetContext);

const VetContextProvider = ({ children, id }) => {
  const reportId = `id${id}`;

  return (
    <VetContext.Provider value={{ reportId }}>
      {children}
    </VetContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default VetContextProvider;
```

In the component receiving the id value from the firestore, pass this to the `VetContextProvider` component and wrap the component tree you want to be able to access the `reportId` value.

```
const id = /* id from firestore ??? */

...

return (
  ...
  <VetContextProvider id={id}> // <-- provides context
    ...
    <EditReportMcs .... />     // <-- consumes context
    ...
    <ViewReportMcs />          // <-- consumes context
    ...
  </VetContextProvider>
  ...
);
```

Both `EditReportMcs` and `ViewReportMcs` use the `useVetContext` hook to access `reportId`.

```
const EditReportMcs = ({ antibiotics, sensitivity }) => {
  const { reportId } = useVetContext();

  ...
};
```

```
const ViewReportMcs = () => {
  const { reportId } = useVetContext();

  ...
};
```